# EF Core Include() in Many to Many relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, lazy-loading, entity-framework-core

The relation between  *Product* and *Customer* is of type many-to-many (from a design point a view).

Using EF Core, we split this relation in two one-to-many relations with a third entity: *ProductCustomer*

```
public partial class ProductCustomer
{
    public long ProductId { get; set; }
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }   
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UsageRecord> UsageRecord { get; set; }
}
```

*UsageRecord* is a list of Records containing the quantity of data used by a certain customer while he is using a product

```
public partial class UsageRecord
{
     public long Id { get; set; }
     public long ProductId { get; set; }
     public long CustomerId { get; set; }           
     public decimal Quantity { get; set; }                
     public virtual ProductCustomer ProductCustomer { get; set; }                
}
```

Now, if i try to read a specific *UsageRecord*,  the *ProductCustomer* object is *null* (perfect, i am using an eager loading approach)

```
return _usageRecordEntity.Where(x => x.ProductId == productId).AsEnumerable();
```

[image: VS2017 - debug]

But if i specifically ask to Include() the *ProductCustomer* entity, the entity framwork, not only includes all the recursive references but also includes the *Product* object and NOT the *Customer*!

```
return _usageRecordEntity.Where(x => x.ProductId == productId).Include(p => p.ProductCustomer).AsEnumerable();
```

[image: vs 2017-debug]

First thing: I don't understand why it is including the whole chain of objects 
if i specifically ask just for the *ProductCustomer* one.

Second thing: Why the *Product* and NOT the *Customer*?!

---

I include for completeness the Context model:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.customerId)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("CustomerId")
                .HasMaxLength(255);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductCustomer>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.ProductId, e.CustomerId })
                .HasName("PK__ProductCustomerComposite");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Customer)
                .WithMany(p => p.ProductCustomer)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.CustomerId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
                .HasConstraintName("FK__ProductCu__CustomerId");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Product)
                .WithMany(p => p.ProductCustomer)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.ProductId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
                .HasConstraintName("FK__ProductCu__ProductId");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<UsageRecord>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Quantity)
                .HasColumnType("decimal")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("0");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.ProductCustomer)
                .WithMany(p => p.UsageRecord)
                .HasForeignKey(d => new { d.ProductId, d.CustomerId })
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_UsageRecordProductcustomer");
        });
    }
```

Comment: There are no many-to-many relations in EF Core, yet. I think you mean, two one-to-many relations.

Comment: Yes of course. Product - Customer is a Many to Many relationship from a design point of view. But it is modelled as two one to many relations with a third entity "ProductCustomer"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically the answer is provided by the following **Tip** in the *Loading Related Data - Eager loading* section of the EF Core [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) (highlight is mine):

> Entity Framework Core will automatically fix-up navigation properties to any other entities that were previously loaded into the context instance. **So even if you don't explicitly include the data for a navigation property, the property may still be populated** if some or all of the related entities were previously loaded.